# Why Enum.concat is much more slower than ++ while concatenating lists?

Tags: elixir, benchmarking

I tried to do some quick benchmarking using [Benchfella](https://github.com/alco/benchfella):

```rb
defmodule ConcatListBench do
  use Benchfella

  @a1 Enum.to_list(1..10_000)
  @a2 Enum.to_list(10_000..20_0000)

  bench "++" do
    @a1 ++ @a2
  end

  bench "Enum.concat" do
    Enum.concat(@a1, @a2)
  end
end
```

And while running it:

```
$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
Elixir 1.4.0-dev (762e7de)

$ mix bench
Settings:
  duration:      1.0 s

## ConcatListBench
[10:01:09] 1/2: ++
[10:01:20] 2/2: Enum.concat

Finished in 14.03 seconds

## ConcatListBench
benchmark na iterations   average time
++           1000000000   0.01 µs/op
Enum.concat       50000   45.03 µs/op
```

The question is how `Enum.concat` could be slower (over 4k times) if [it uses](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L441-L443) `++` operator internally for lists ?

I understand that guard clauses in `Enum.concat` and pattern matching costs some time, but benchmark shows a big difference, isn't it ?

**UPDATE:** This happens due to [Constant Folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), concatenation using `++` optimized at compile time and takes instant time to be run. So the benchmark is not quite realistic.

Comment: Because `Enum.concat` would work for anything, implementing `Enumerable` protocol and pattern matching in `concat` costs.

Comment: Yes, but i do not expect it to be 4k times slower... Maybe benchmark is not quite apposite.

Comment: It is 4k times slower because `List#++/2` costs literally nothing. You likely compare the pattern matching, that costs against [not exactly of course] `noop`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer: [Constant Folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

Longer answer: Module attributes in Elixir are replaced with their literal values when Elixir is compiled to `beam` files. For example, the following code:

```
defmodule ConcatListBench do
  @a1 Enum.to_list(1..10)
  @a2 Enum.to_list(10..20)

  def plusplus, do: @a1 ++ @a2

  def concat, do: Enum.concat(@a1, @a2)
end
```

compiles to:

```
-module('Elixir.ConcatListBench').
... 
concat() ->
    'Elixir.Enum':concat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
             [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]).

plusplus() ->
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] ++
      [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20].
```

The Erlang compiler's [`sys_core_fold`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/compiler/src/sys_core_fold.erl) module, which does constant folding optimization, [evaluates `++` operations as much as possible at compile time](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/fde238fb52133a6c7a2a3f2a2e16f1c1bef62394/lib/compiler/src/sys_core_fold.erl#L950-L967). Since in this case, both the lists are literals, it can completely eliminate the function call and replace it with the resulting list. So in your benchmark, the `++` function is just returning a list that already exists in the VM. It's as fast as doing `1 + 2` (which is also constant folded to `3`):

```
...
bench "1 + 2" do
  1 + 2
end
...
```

```
## ConcatListBench
benchmark na iterations   average time
1 + 2        1000000000   0.01 µs/op
++           1000000000   0.01 µs/op
Enum.concat       50000   37.89 µs/op
```

A more realistic benchmark would be to do an indirect call to `++` which the Erlang compiler does not fold:

```
def plus_plus(a, b), do: a ++ b

bench "++" do
  plus_plus(@a1, @a2)
end
```

These are the outputs of 3 runs:

```
## ConcatListBench
benchmark na iterations   average time
Enum.concat       50000   37.44 µs/op
++                50000   41.65 µs/op

## ConcatListBench
benchmark na iterations   average time
++                50000   36.07 µs/op
Enum.concat       50000   38.58 µs/op

## ConcatListBench
benchmark na iterations   average time
Enum.concat       50000   39.34 µs/op
++                50000   40.74 µs/op
```

So really, if your lists aren't constant at compile time, both ways are just as fast. I would expect `Enum.concat` to be a tiny bit slower (especially for small lists) as it does a bit more work than `++`.

Comment: Thanks. That explains